# socketpair() can be used in place of pipe2() and should be supported in all kernel versions?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, pipe, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Using `O_DIRECT` option in `pipe2()` is only supported by Linux since 3.4 kernel. I have kernel 2.6 where an `O_DIRECT` option is not supported. So `socketpair()` can replace the `pipe2()`.

My code snippet:

```
if( pipe2( dx_evq, O_DIRECT | O_CLOEXEC ) ){perror( "pipe2 failure" );exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}
```

In our Daemon code, we call `pipe2()` with a requested option of `O_DIRECT` as part of the Daemon initialization process.

We are getting this following error:

> pipe2 failure: Invalid Argument

Comment: Why not just drop `O_DIRECT`? Why do you need `O_DIRECT`?

Comment: I can't because it is synchronous, I don't want to make it as asynchronous. If there is any way to replace it with socketpair.